# Saving and retrieving data from NSMutablearray

Tags: iphone

I have a NSMutableArray holding string data.

I want to save my data. 
When i turn off the application and relaunch the application my saved data need to be presented.

And I need to know where the file saved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving a NSArray.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487606/saving-a-nsarray)

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically the same as yours: [Saving a NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487606/saving-a-nsarray)

Another option is to save it in `NSUserDefaults`.