# How to store a double[][] into a file or anything persistent in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, persistence

I have a double[n][20] where n may be up to 200. How to store it to a file?

Comment: Is your purpose to store for later readback or store text for reading outside you app somehow?

Comment: @trumpetlicks, for later readback.

Comment: Then you may want to store the values in binary format.  This will be faster, take up less space and preserve value precision when you read back in! I will try and leave sample code later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either write my own file writing routine in ANSI-C or use the NSArray writing to file capability.  Depends on preference.

[Saving a NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487606/saving-a-nsarray)

I actually wrote a snippet of code to make sure this would work on the iOS platform.  I am going to post the hole thing here and you can pick and choose what you want.  Essentially I created a static array of 5 x 5 for test, but it will work for any sized array.  This gives code for both writing the file in binary format (the quickest method and the best method for preserving the original double' precision), and reading it back.  As you can see I implemented the main code in a UIViewController' viewDidLoad routine.  I filled the array with randoms (not really as I seeded the rand routine with a static 79).

In the header file I have defined

```
double values[5][5];


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle * myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString * absPath  = [myBundle resourcePath];
    NSString * currPath;

    srand(79);

    FILE * aFile;
    currPath=[absPath stringByAppendingString: @"/myfile.bin"];
    if( NULL == ( aFile = fopen([currPath cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],"rb") ) ){

        //Generate some random doubles
        printf("generating 5 x 5 random values\r\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                values[i][j] = (double)rand() / (double)rand();
                printf("%.3f, ", values[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\r\n");
        }

        aFile = fopen([currPath cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],"wb");
        fwrite (values , 1 , sizeof(double) * 5 * 5 , aFile );
        fclose(aFile);

    }else{
        printf("File myfile.bin exists.  Reading in File.\r\n");
        fread(&values, sizeof(double), 5 * 5, aFile);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                printf("%.3f, ", values[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\r\n");
        }
        fclose(aFile);
    }

}
```

The Output from the code (in the console window looks as follows)

```
generating 5 x 5 random values
0.002, 2.969, 0.298, 1.137, 0.790,
8.753, 0.884, 0.264, 0.034, 1.033, 
3.848, 1.049, 1.350, 0.402, 2.192, 
4.284, 0.979, 0.162, 1.294, 0.339, 
0.830, 0.175, 0.633, 1.008, 1.142, 

[Session started at 2012-06-02 03:56:44 +0000.]
File myfile.bin exists.  Reading in File.
0.002, 2.969, 0.298, 1.137, 0.790, 
8.753, 0.884, 0.264, 0.034, 1.033, 
3.848, 1.049, 1.350, 0.402, 2.192, 
4.284, 0.979, 0.162, 1.294, 0.339, 
0.830, 0.175, 0.633, 1.008, 1.142,
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can't put doubles in an NSArray - you would have to wrap them in NSNumber objects, perhaps not worth the cost.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fcntl.h> // for open(), close()
#include <unistd.h> // for write()

int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY|O_BINARY); // system call
write(fd, d, sizeof(double)*n*20);
close(fd);
```

http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/open/

http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/write/

Comment: I can't find this write() in the documentation.

Comment: write() is a standard C function, and it uses file descriptors (int) instead of file pointers (FILE*). It is a lower level function (I think it's a syscall?) than the f* functions.

Comment: O_WRONLY | O_BINARY for binary output

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
void writeData(double[][20] data, int n, const char name[]) {
    FILE* output = fopen(name, "w");
    int i, j;
    fprintf(output, "%d\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            fprintf(output, "%lf\n", data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

double** readData(const char name[]) {
    FILE* input = fopen(name, "r");
    int i, j, n;
    fscanf(input, "%d", &n);
    double** ret = (double**)malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret[i] = (double*)malloc(20*sizeof(double));
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            fscanf(input, "%lf", &ret[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

FYI, this is untested code, but it should give you an idea of how to do this. This is simply a text file with the first line containing the length (n), and the rest of the lines containing the doubles.

You could also use a plist, because the  tags can hold doubles. Use NSNumber*s to write the doubles, nested within s.

```
void writeData(double** data, int n, const char name[]) {
    FILE* output = fopen(name, "w");
    int i, j;
    fprintf(output, "%d\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < LPCC_DIM; j++) {
            fprintf(output, "%lf\n", data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

double** readData(const char name[], int* getN) {
    FILE* input = fopen(name, "r");
    int n;
    fscanf(input, "%d\n", &n);
    *getN = n;
    double** ret = (double**)malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret[i] = (double*)malloc(LPCC_DIM*sizeof(double));
        for(int j = 0; j < LPCC_DIM; j++) {
            fscanf(input, "%lf", &ret[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It seems that it's not working. Are you sure this will work? I fixed the compilation error.

Comment: I think this will have precision problems with the %1f.  Either way printing a double almost always loses precision and if you print to preserve, then it will take quite a bit more space once the file is written.