# What is the best way to save an array to a file that can be reloaded

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, storage

Similar to how a game allows you to save your progress, I have an application in iOS that stores a user's progress in a single array.  I would like to store that array to a file so that when the user reopens their app this file loads their current status.

Comment: agreed thanks for the clarifying question.  I have updated the question to target iOS.

Comment: No, do not add your technologies to the title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Questions that ask for the "best" way are generally opinion-based, if not too broad.

Comment: @JAL Not necessarily. Nothing wrong with asking for best practices *in principle*.

Comment: @LeoNatan I disagree.  The question can be reworded to not focus on a "best way," but questions like these are off-topic, either POB or too broad.  In this case I believe that this question is too broad. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265928/2415822

Comment: Also this is a duplicate of many older questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487606/2415822, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5413851/2415822, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26233067/2415822, etc.  Just use google.

Comment: @JAL I didn't find anything specific to swift 3 thus the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` pair and be sure each of the objects in the array is conforming to `NSCoding`. You could read [here](http://mhorga.org/2015/08/25/ios-persistence-with-nscoder-and-nskeyedarchiver.html) about it.

```
  NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myArray, toFile: filePath)
```

and then unarchiving

```
if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as? [Any] {
    objects = array
}
```

Here is an example object conforming to `NSCoding` (taken from the article linked above):

```
class Person : NSObject, NSCoding {

    struct Keys {
        static let Name = "name"
        static let Age = "age"
    }

    var name = ""
    var age = 0

    init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        name = dictionary[Keys.Name] as! String
        age = dictionary[Keys.Age] as! Int
    }

    public func encode(with archiver: NSCoder) {
        archiver.encodeObject(name, forKey: Keys.Name)
        archiver.encodeObject(age, forKey: Keys.Age)
    }

    required init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        name = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Name) as! String
        age = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Age) as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `NSKeyedArchiver` to store a normal array into `NSUserDefaults`, you only need it if its an array of custom objects.

Comment: @Rikh: yes, but this is the most general case, I assume the game state in any non-trivial app would use some kind of custom objects.

Comment: @Rikh, You can only save an array to user defaults if all the objects are property list objects, as mentioned in my answer. There are a LOT of types of system objects that are not custom, but are not in the very short list of property list objects.

Comment: @Rikh, also note that the OP asked about saving an array to a file, not saving to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Ah my mistake then! I had no idea about system objects! I assumed incorrectly that you would normally use either property list objects or models!

Answer (score 1):

If the objects in your array are all "property list objects" (dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers (integer and float), dates, binary data, and Boolean values) then you could use the array method `write(toFile:atomically:)` to save your array to a file, and then reload the resulting file with `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` or `init(contentsOfFile:)`.

If you have objects in your array's `object graph` that are not property list objects then that approach won't work. In that case, @BogdanFarca's suggestion of using `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` would be a good way to go.

Comment: This sounds like the right way to go.  I've been searching for a clear example of how to do this for an array in Swift 3.0 but haven't found anything.  Can you point me to a working example of how to do this?

Comment: It's one line of code. `array.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)`. The path needs to point to a directory that you are allowed to write to, like the documents directory.